# Adding new columns to a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a list containing the column names of a dataframe. I want to add these empty columns to a dataframe that already exists.

```
col_names = ["a", "b", "e"]
df = pd.Dataframe()
df = # stores some content
```

I understand a single new column can be added in the following manner and I could do the same for other columns

```
df['e'] = None
```

However, I'd like to know how to add these new columns at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same syntax as adding a single new column:

```
df[col_names] = None
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create the data frame, you can pass the `col_names` to the `columns` parameter:

```
import pandas as pd

col_names = ["a", "b", "e"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)

print(df)
# Empty DataFrame
# Columns: [a, b, e]
# Index: []

print(df.columns)
# Index(['a', 'b', 'e'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply give `df[col_list] = None`. Here's an example of how you can do it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['river','sea','lake','pond','ocean'],
                   'year':[2000,2001,2002,2003,2004],
                   'col2':['apple','peach','banana','grape','cherry']})
print (df)
```

Created a dataframe with 3 columns and 5 rows:

Output of df is:

```
    col1  year    col2
0  river  2000   apple
1    sea  2001   peach
2   lake  2002  banana
3   pond  2003   grape
4  ocean  2004  cherry
```

Now I want to add columns `['a','b','c','d','e']` to the df. I can do it by just assigning `None` to the column list.

```
temp_cols = ['a','b','c','d','e']
df[temp_cols] = None
print (df)
```

The updated dataframe will have:

```
    col1  year    col2     a     b     c     d     e
0  river  2000   apple  None  None  None  None  None
1    sea  2001   peach  None  None  None  None  None
2   lake  2002  banana  None  None  None  None  None
3   pond  2003   grape  None  None  None  None  None
4  ocean  2004  cherry  None  None  None  None  None
```

Answer (score 1):

`assign` with `dict.fromkeys` also works

```
In [219]: df = pd.DataFrame()

In [220]: df.assign(**dict.fromkeys(col_names))

Out[220]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, e]
Index: []
```

---

This is also work for adding empty (`None` values) columns to an existing dataframe

sample `df`

```
np.random.seed(20)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 4, 3*2).reshape(3,2), columns=['col1','col2'])

Out[240]:
   col1  col2
0     3     2
1     3     3
2     0     2

df = df.assign(**dict.fromkeys(col_names))

Out[242]:
   col1  col2     a     b     e
0     3     2  None  None  None
1     3     3  None  None  None
2     0     2  None  None  None
```

Comment: and concat to original ;)

Comment: @jezrael: I thought OP question is on adding columns to an existing empty dataframe, so I don't add back to existing dataframe. I know it is odd, but that is what I understand of the question.

Comment: @jezrael: ah, thanks friend :). This method also works with existing non-empty dataframe. I just edited the answer to add example.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, working for existing df, done ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please try [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

```
#To add to an existing dataframe
df=df.reindex(list(df.columns)+col_names, axis='columns', fill_value='None') 

     Name         Weight     a     b     e
0    John        Average  None  None  None
1    Paul  Below Average  None  None  None
2  Darren  Above Average  None  None  None
3    John        Average  None  None  None
4  Darren  Above Average  None  None  None
```